# PHP form finding days in a month from a select option within a form

Tags: php, html, forms

i am trying to get a form that posts to it's self after it is submitted. what i need is all the months in a select box when submitted the return is how many days are in that month. looking like this "the month of December (2015) has 31 days"

the code i currently have doesn't get every month only December and when i press submit the select box and submit button are still visible

this is my current code

```
    <?php
    $months = array(1 => 'January', 'Feburary', 'March',
        'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
        'September', 'October', 'November', 'December',);
    //var_dump($months);

    $curmonth = date("n");

    echo " <form name='test' method='post' action='#'> <select name='month'>\n";

    foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
        $option = strtoupper($value);

        if ($key == $curmonth)
            echo "<option selected value=\"$key\">$option</option>\n";
        else
            echo "<option value=\"$key\">$option</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n <br> <input type='submit'> </form>";


    if ($_POST['month']) {

        $month = ucfirst(strtolower($option));
        $number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $key, 2015);
        echo 'the month of ' . $month . ' (2015) has ' . $number . 'days';
        echo "<a href='assignment_10.php>Check days for another month</a>";
    }
    ?>
```

please help me i am new to this and getting very frusturated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting `$key` instead of submitted month, which is actually last month of your select options. Fix like this.

```
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $_POST['month'], 2015);
```

Or if you want to do it your way :

```
$month = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['month'])); //You have put $option which has value from the last item in select
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, 2015); //You have put $key which has value from the last item in select
```